# SQLite prepending zeros

Tags: sqlite

Does anyone know how to prepend leading zeros to a column in sqlite?
I am getting columns like 1, 2 and for our data import they need to be 3 character codes with leading zeros.

I've tried this

```
update LockBox
set CustomField2 = case
             when CustomField2 = '1' then '001'
             end
WHERE CustomField2 = '1';
```

but does not give me the correct result.  I'm probably doing this wrong. I'm more of a sql server guy not a sqlite person
I would do this in SQL Server

```
 SELECT RIGHT('000'+CAST(field AS VARCHAR(3)),3)
```

How can I accomplish this in SQLite.  I want to update the table then export to CSV to import into our business application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `substr`:

```
update LockBox
set CustomField2 = substr('000' || CustomField2, -3, 3);
```

provided that all values in `CustomField2` are no longer than 3 digits.

Comment: getting this error
    near "select": syntax error: update LockBox
set CustomField2 = select

Answer (score 0):

Define the column as **[text](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)**?

```
$ sqlite3 types
sqlite> create table T( i integer, c text );
sqlite> insert into T values ( '001', '001' );
sqlite> select * from T;
i           c         
----------  ----------
1           001
```